# Загрузка пакетов с помощью npm в другой каталог

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm

Вопрос вот в чем, npm сваливает все пакеты в node_modules. Но в этой куче зависимостей не очень удобно работать с плагинами идущими на продакшн.

Как настроить npm чтобы загружать плагины в каталог, допустим libs, для дальнейшего подключения в проект?

Comment: Для этого в `package.json` предусмотрены разные поля: `dependecies` и `devDependecies`

Comment: Для этого это для чего? Список установленных пакетов не дает возможности работать с самими пакетами, нужно лезть в node_modules и искать пакет там, а это не очень удобно. Нужно чтобы пакеты сохранялись в другой каталог.

Comment: Эээ? А зачем вообще туда лезть? Что вы с ними такого делаете?

Comment: да самое элементарное посмотреть путь к файлу плагина уже заставляет лезть в node_modules. Под пакетами я имею ввиду сторонние библиотеки и плагины.

Comment: Хм. Смысл модуля же в том, что быть цельным. Зачем знать где там какие файлы лежат? Похоже что вы что-то используете неправильно/не по назначением.

Comment: Например мне всё равно где и как лежат файлы в пакете `lodash`. Я просто пишу `const lodash = require('lodash');` и всё.

Comment: Понял. Я еще "зеленый" в программировании, но усердно тружусь )). Спасибо за комменты.